# React Native - Logout - Can't perform a React state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, logout

Actually i'm working on an app mobile, everyday i discover some new practises on React (i'm junior) and today i need help about a function : User Logout.

My Logout function is in Profil.js, inside an IconButton, when is pressed my function Logout is called

Profil.js

```
    const Loggout = () => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("@LoggedIn", "false");

        ToastMsgNotification.CustomSuccess("Déconnexion", "Vous avez été déconnecté")
        route.params.refreshApp()
    }
```

My problem is in App.js after the route.params.refreshApp (works) !

App.js

```
async function CheckingSession() {
    let UserLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@LoggedIn");

    return UserLoggedIn;
}

async function CheckingAuth() {
    let UserToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@JWT')
    let UserLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@LoggedIn');

    if (UserLoggedIn != "true" && UserToken == null)
        return false;

    if (UserToken)
    { 
        let checkUserToken = await axiosInstance.post('/api/login/check_jwt', UserToken, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': UserToken,
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((answer) => {
            return answer.data.JWT;
        });

        if (checkUserToken == "OK")
            return true;
        
        ToastMsgNotification.CustomError("Accès expiré", "Merci de vous reconnecter à votre compte");

        return false;
    }
}

export default function App(props) {
    const [refreshPage, setRefreshPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [loaded] = useFonts({
        MontserratM: require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
        MontserratB: require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
        MontserratSB: require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
        MontserratR: require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
        MontserratL: require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
        MontserratXB: require('../../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    });
    const ref = React.useRef(null);
    const [userLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
    const isMounted = React.useRef(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            return await CheckingAuth()
        }

        fetchData().then(r => (isMounted.current) ? setRefreshPage(refreshPage + 1) : '')

        const fetchSession = async () => {
            return await CheckingSession()
        }

        fetchSession().then((r) => { 
            setUserLoggedIn(r)
        })
    }, [])


    if (!loaded) {
        return null;
    }

    CheckingSession().then((r) => {
        setUserLoggedIn(r)
    })

    return (
        <NavigationContainer ref={ref}>
            <StatusBar style="dark" />
            { userLoggedIn == "true" ? 
                (<NavigationLoggedIn refreshApp={() => setRefreshPage(refreshPage + 1)} />) :
                (<NavigationNotLoggedIn refreshApp={() => setRefreshPage(refreshPage + 1)} />)
            }
            <Toast config={toastConfig} style={{position: 'absolute'}}/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

I understand issue source is : **setUserLoggedIn(r)** in **CheckingSession().then()** after the **if (!loaded)**

But i really dont understand how to fix the error : Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function, in SvgUri..............

If someone can help me, thanks a lot !

i've try abortController, useIsMounted, but i really dont understand...
i've try to add UseEffect in Profil.js but an error spawn too

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but usage of [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) would make things simpler. Context provides a way to pass the login state through the component tree.

Here is the minimal example.

```
const AuthContext = createContext()

function Toolbar({login}) {
  const {loggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext)
  return <Button title={loggedIn ? "Logout": "Login"} onPress={login}/>
}

function Content() {
  const {loggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext)
  return <>
    { loggedIn ? <Text>User is logged in</Text> : <Text>Please log in</Text> }
  </>
}

function Screen() {
  const {loggedIn, setLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext)
  return <>
    <Toolbar login={() => setLoggedIn(!loggedIn)} />
    <Content/>
  </>
}

function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() =>  {
    const getLoggedIn = async () => {
      const loggedIn = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedIn'))
      setLoggedIn(loggedIn)
    }
    getLoggedIn()
  }, [])

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{
      loggedIn,
      setLoggedIn: (value) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("loggedIn", JSON.stringify(value))
        setLoggedIn(value)
      },
    }}>
    <Screen/>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
}

export default App
```

Please refer to [AuthFlow](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/example/src/Screens/AuthFlow.tsx) for a more detailed one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I will check doc about Context, thanks again